# KFAS 1.0.4 thetahat - Smoothed signals extraction

Tags: r, package, output

I have been using the **KFAS** package; it’s great.

I updated the package to version **1.0.4** (from **1.0.2**) and maybe the use of the function has changed slightly, but I have trouble getting smoothed estimates of the signal (thetahat, which is stated in the documentation). I run the following line of code, which used to give me an output which included the smoothed estimates:

```
out   <-KFS(model,smoothing=c("signal"))
```

`out$thetahat` used to contain the smoothed signals in the previous version but not this one.

Has the syntax for this function changed to get these?

Comment: What model form you have? It really depends on the model you set up at the first place , for example, gaussion or non-gaussion? Please provide your exact SSModel.